# How do I fix my infinite scroll table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working to build an **infinite** scroll table populated with fakejs users' name, email and address data created by json-server. I want to display 50 data points per page, and then when scrolling down to the end of the page, another 50 data points would load. How can I achieve that? I see that my code is not working so far because when I scroll down, its not loading another batch of data ...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentPageNumber = 1;
  loadData(currentPageNumber);
  if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() -           $(window).height()){  
      currentPageNumber +=1;
    loadData(currentPageNumber);
    }
});
function loadData(currentPage){
  $.ajax({
      method: "get",
      url: "http://localhost:3000/users?_page="+currentPage +"&_limit=50",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
              for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                 $('#tbl tbody').append("<tr><td>"+ data[i].name+"</td><td>"+ 
                 data[i].email+"</td><td>" 
                 + data[i].city + "," + data[i].country+ "</td></tr>")
              }; 


      },
      error: function(data) {
              console.log("Something went wrong!");
      }
})
}
```

```css
table {width:100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
td, th { border: 1px solid black; }
tr { background: #ccc; }
tr:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
td > div { white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Infinite Scrolling</h1>

<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Email Address</td>
      <td>Physical Address</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can limit data selection from database based on upset and limit.
Have a look to [Retrieving data from inner join using LIMIT and OFFSET](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31873/retrieving-data-from-inner-join-using-limit-and-offset)

And `loadData(currentPageNumber);` to [`scroll()`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event after the first call to `loadData(currentPageNumber);` so that your data loads on first load and call `loadData(currentPageNumber);` when the user scroll to the end of the page.

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentPageNumber = 1;
    loadData(currentPageNumber);
    
    
                    $(window).on("scroll", function () {
                        var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
                        var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
                        if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
                        currentPageNumber +=1;
                         loadData(currentPageNumber);
                        }
                    });
    
    function loadData(currentPage){
        $.ajax({
            method: "get",
            url: "http://localhost:3000/users?_page="+currentPage,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                       $('#tbl tbody').append("<tr><td>"+ data[i].name+"</td><td>"+ 
                       data[i].email+"</td><td>" 
                       + data[i].city + "," + data[i].country+ "</td></tr>")
                    }; 


            },
            error: function(data) {
                    console.log("Something went wrong!");
            }
    })
    }

})


<head>
    <title>Infinite Scroll Table</title>
    <style>

        table { border-collapse: collapse; }
        td, th { border: 1px solid black; }
        tr { background: #ccc; }
        tr:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
        td > div { white-space: pre; }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
        <h1>Infinite Scrolling</h1>

        <table id="tbl">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td>Email Address</td>
                                <td>Physical Address</td>


                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
        </table>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="table.js"></script>         
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you ! But it's so strange that it works on Internet Explorer. But in Chrome, it only works when I scroll all the way up to the top, but doesn't work when I scroll to the end of the page...

Answer (score 0):

Your code only check 1 time when the document loaded. You have to check and load data everytime you scroll so you should bind it to scroll event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentPageNumber = 1;
    loadData(currentPageNumber);
    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
         if($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() > $('body').height() - $(window).height() / 2){
             currentPageNumber +=1;
             loadData(currentPageNumber);
         }
    }
    //your loadData function
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not run because you only call checking position only once time.
To make it run, you should tracking the mouse's scroll event, for ex:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var currentPageNumber = 1;
      loadData(currentPageNumber);
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() ==  $(document).height()) {
          loadData(currentPageNumber);
        }
      });

     function loadData(currentPage){
        console.log("test");
      }

   })
```